# Mongoose populate subdocument in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, populate

I have a Mongoose offer model explained below:

```
const OfferSchema = new Schema({
  sections: [
    {
      title: String,
    },
  ],
});
```

and order schema which has reference to to the first schema offer explained below:

```
const OrderSchema = new Schema({
  offers: [
    {
      offer: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Offer' },
      sections: [
        {
          section: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Offer.sections' }, // issue here
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
});
```

the problem that I can not populate sections here `{section: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Offer.sections' }}`

it gives me `MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Offer.sections".`

so is there any way to populate sections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Mongoose doesn't support this feature.
check the Github issue [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6654)

The alternative solution you can embed **sections** into the order schema